# Trying to do a flutter pub get and got Process finished with exit code 66

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
Running "flutter pub get" in mobile...                          
Because mobile depends on charts_flutter from path which doesn't exist (could not find package charts_flutter at "../mobile-dependencies/pub.dartlang.org/charts_flutter-0.12.0"), version solving failed.
pub get failed (66; Because mobile depends on charts_flutter from path which doesn't exist (could not find package charts_flutter at "../mobile-dependencies/pub.dartlang.org/charts_flutter-0.12.0"), version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 66


/Users/H025712/development/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in mobile...                          
Because mobile depends on charts_flutter from path which doesn't exist (could not find package charts_flutter at "../mobile-dependencies/pub.dartlang.org/charts_flutter-0.12.0"), version solving failed.
pub get failed (66; Because mobile depends on charts_flutter from path which doesn't exist (could not find package charts_flutter at "../mobile-dependencies/pub.dartlang.org/charts_flutter-0.12.0"), version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:** Someone in your team (could be yourself) add a plugin from their local folder. This plugin can't be found when you try to update the dependency.

**Quick fix:** If you use remote git, let you teammate include that plugin in the project folder, modify the pubspec.yaml path, add it to stage, commit then push. In the case not using git remote, copy those files to your computer in the path as pub spec.yaml suggested.

**Ideal fix:** Let your teammate use public plugin or share that plugin in private with password, then let flutter download that plugin by flutter pub get/upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `pubspec.yaml` is well ordered, I had badly composed dev_dependencies and it failed me

Answer (score 0):

Talked to my tech lead, who is familiar with the code; he said to check out the missing code that was referencing overrides in the `pubspec.yaml`:

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies

> #### Dependency overrides
>
> You can use `dependency_overrides` to temporarily override all references to a dependency.
>
> For example, perhaps you are updating a local copy of transmogrify, a
> published library package. Transmogrify is used by other packages in
> your dependency graph, but you don’t want to clone each package
> locally and change each pubspec to test your local copy of
> transmogrify.
>
> In this situation, you can override the dependency using
> `dependency_overrides` to specify the directory holding the local copy
> of the package.
>
> The pubspec would look something like the following:
>
> ```
> name: my_app
> dependencies:
>   transmogrify: ^1.2.0
> dependency_overrides:
>   transmogrify:
>     path: ../transmogrify_patch/
> ```